# Text-base game inventory list (Python)

Tags: python

so I'm new to python and I am making a text base game. I created an inventory list and in case the player picks up an item more than once, the second time it should be able to give a message saying that they already have this item. I got it to work to an extent where the item doesn't go over the value more than one, but it does not print the message. Please help!!

```
elif decision == "use H on comb":
            global inventory
            if inventory.count("comb")>1:
                print ("You already got this item.")
                print ("")
                print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
            if inventory.count("comb")<1:
                print ("(pick up comb)")
                print ("You went over to the table and picked up the comb,")
                print ("it's been added to your inventory.")
                add_to_inventory("comb")
                print("")
                print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
            game()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the `in` operator to test for membership

```
if "comb" in inventory:
   print("I have found the comb already...")
else:
   print("Nope not here")
```

but as to why your code was failing was that

```
inventory.count('comb') == 1 
# which fails inventory.count('comb') > 1 test
# but also fails inventory.count('comb') < 1 test so its not re added
```

you could have easily solved this yourself by printing the value of `inventory.count('comb')` , which is a useful method for debugging your program for beginners... basically when something doesnt work correctly, try printing it, chances are the variable is not what you think it is...

Answer (score 3):

maybe a little more structuring can be done and avoid using global `inventory` .jsut a basic idea below:

```
def game():
     inventory = []
     # simulate picking up items( replace this loop with your custom logic )
     while True:
         item = raw_input('pick up something')
         if item in inventory: # use in operator to check membership
             print ("you already have got this")
             print (" ".join(inventory))
         else:
             print ("pick up the item")
             print ("its been added to inventory")
             inventory.append(item)
             print (" ".join(inventory))
```